# How do I install Intellij on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: java, 15.04, virtualization, intellij

I keep receiving this error:

```
miguel@Miguel:~$ cd '/home/miguel/Downloads/idea-IU-141.1010.3/bin' 
miguel@Miguel:~/Downloads/idea-IU-141.1010.3/bin$ ./idea.sh
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=350m'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

How do I go about fixing this error?

What I have installed for Java is:

```
oracle-java9-set-default 
oracle-jave9-installer
oracle-java9-unlimited-jce-po
```

Comment: According to [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12114284/2554472), the MaxPermSize option is gone as of Java 8. So try editing `idea.sh` to remove any occurrences of `-XX:MaxPermSize=350m` .

Answer (score 1):

After posting earlier I decided to download the latest available Oracle JDK 8u45 and the latest community version of Intelli-J Idea 14
    ideaIC-14.1.3.tar.gz

```
jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

I ran this script from command line as root to install Oracle JDK, the script assumes you downloaded the jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz to the Downloads directory and you execute the script as root from your home directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

# author:GeoWade

# Create script variables

ETRCJDK="Downloads/jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz"

JVMDIRLIB="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0"

MOVJDK="jdk1.8.0_45/* /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0"

INSJAV="update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/java" 1"

INSJAVC="update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/javac" 1"

INSJAVAWS="update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/javaws" 1"

INSJAVJAR="update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/jar" "jar" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/jar" 1"

INSJAVDOC="update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javadoc" "javadoc" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/javadoc" 1"

INSJAVAPPVIEW="update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/appletviewer" "appletviewer" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/appletviewer" 1"

VRSJAVA="java -version"

TSTJAV="java"
TSTJAVC="javac"
TSTJAVAWS="javaws"
TSTJAVJAR="jar"
TSTJAVDOC="javadoc"

UPD="updatedb"

echo "Extracting jdk-8u45"

tar -xvf $ETRCJDK

echo "Making jdk1.8.0 directory in the jvm directory"

mkdir -p $JVMDIRLIB

echo "jvm/jdk1.8.0 directory is made"

echo "Moving contents of jdk1.8.0_45 to jdk1.8.0"

mv $MOVJDK

echo "contents moved"

echo "installing java"

$INSJAV

echo "installing javac"

$INSJAVC

echo "installing javaws"

$INSJAVAWS

echo "installing jar"

$INSJAVJAR

echo "installing java doc"

$INSJAVDOC

echo "installing appletviewer"

$INSJAVAPPVIEW

echo "Testing java"

$TSTJAV

echo "Testing javac"

$TSTJAVC

echo "Testing javaws"

$TSTJAVAWS

echo "Testing jar"

$TSTJAVJAR

echo "Testing javadoc"

$TSTJAVDOC

echo "This version of the Oracle JDK is:"

$VRSJAVA

$UPD

exit;
```

To execute the script (titled jdk8u45.sh), I ran the following sequence of commands:

```
:~$ chmod +x jdk8u45.sh

:~$ sudo bash

:~# ./jdk8u45.sh

:~# exit
```

Then I extracted the ideaIC-14.1.3.tar.gz, created a directory in the /usr/local directory titled ideaJ, then move the contents of the extracted archive to /usr/local/ideaJ as shown below:

```
:~$ tar -xvf Downloads/ideaIC-14.1.3.tar.gz

:~$ sudo mkdir -p -m0755 /usr/local/ideaJ

:~$ sudo cp -rf idea-IC-141.1010.3/* /usr/local/ideaJ/
```

after doing so I change directories to /usr/local/ideaJ/bin and ran the idea.sh script as shown below:

```
:~$ cd /usr/local/ideaJ/bin

:/usr/local/ideaJ/bin$ ./idea.sh
```

I photo cataloged the process

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the 14 version of the Idea, with the Oracle JDK 8u45, the parameter is ignored. Your problem is the javaagenttool of /usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar or however its spelled. I don't even have that jar installed on my system.

You can copy the script into gedit and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a JVM installed? You can check it by typing this command at 
command line:

```
:~$ java -version
```

If it says the java command is not found, you don't have a jvm.

If not install the latest Oracle JDK from this link:

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
```

I created directory for go-ide in /usr/local, e.g.:

```
:~$ sudo mkdir -p -m0755 /usr/local/go-ide

:~$ sudo cp -rf $HOME/Downloads/intelli-j-archive-extract/* /usr/local/go-ide/

:~$ cd /usr/local/go-ide/../

:~$ ./idea.sh
```

And it worked fine, it searched for my jvm (which I had already installed and updated the alternatives to give a sym-link for java, javac, jar, and java-doc) and it was off to the races.

If you haven't installed a JVM, let me know. After you download the tar gunzip archive from Oracle and I'll post a bash script that will automate the installation of the JVM (jdk).

Comment: No that didn't resolve the error, thanks for your input though.